# Why is the variable value being passed here

Tags: javascript, scope

I wrote the following code with two functions `a()` and `b()`.

The function `a()` has a loop as shown below and within that loop it calls the function `b()`. The problem is that the loop counter of the first function gets its value from `b()` and then stops. No values are being passed between the two functions and the only thing that they have in common is the name of the variable.

Can anyone explain what exactly is happening here?

As per my understanding, they both should have their own copy of `x`, unless I declare `x` to be global.

http://jsfiddle.net/rahulkadukar/s2gs9j05/

```
a();

function a() {
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        console.log(x); 
        b();
        console.log(x);
     }
}

function b(){
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        //Do nothing 
    }
}
```

The output of the above function is

> 0
>   4

Comment: This is exactly why you should always run in strict mode because it would flag this as an error as an attempt to use an undeclared variable is an error in strict mode rather than an implicit creation of a global variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you didn't declare the variables as local variables with the `var` keyword, they're global variables. So both functions are using the same variable `x`. Change it to:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++)
```

and they'll be local variables within each function.

Comment: So, unless I explicitly use the var keyword, the variables are global. I did not know that, thank you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

in your case x is not declare inside for loop.so it is assumed as global variable.use this:

```
a();

function a(){
  for(var x = 0; x < 4; x++){
    console.log(x); 
    b();
    console.log(x);
  }
}

function b(){
  for(var x = 0; x < 4; x++){
    //Do nothing 
  }
}
```